# Stream Corrupted and Cannot assign instance of... errors when reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to develop a game using sockets. In one part of it I need to transfer the board of one player to another, so I take the object in which it is stored and send it trough the socket. When I receive the players board in the socket of the other player I get an error message. This error message is not always the same, sometimes it is a StreamCorruptedException and other times it is a ClassCastException. This error does not happens always at the same times, in example, sometimes I send the board from one player to another 15 times before there occurs an error and other times I send it just three times and the error occurs. The stack trace for the Stream corruption is the following

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1381)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1714)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at guerradelosmundos.threadCliente.run(threadCliente.java:144)
```

The stack trace for the other error is similar. The interesting part is that both occur on the same line of code, which is the following

```
    Tablero tablero=(Tablero)entrada.readObject();
```

The line where I write the information to the socket is the following

```
synchronized(this){
   foo.salida.writeObject(too);
   foo.salida.flush();                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without the code but here are some ideas:

- are you trying to call readObject more times than you actually called writeObject (or before)?
- are you reading/writing something else to the stream?
- are you stopping the sending process before the reading takes place?
- are you messing with the object fields at the client side without updating the client (or vice-versa)?

Comment: What do you mean by updating the client?

Comment: I mean changing the code for the class where you are sending it but forgetting to put the change in the part of the code that reads. This is assuming you have two independent processes for writing and reading. For instance, you may have changed Tablero class but the client (the one reading) is still using an old version of Tablero.